# Как удалить строчку в БД не по ID

Tags: android

Есть ListView.

БД из 10 строчек пронумерованных по ID от 1 до 10.

Если выбрать в listView 0 элемент, то данные из БД выберутся из 1 строчки с ID==1.

Так вот, если удалить в БД строчку с ID==3 и заново запустить ListView то строки в БД сместятся вниз. Короче будет вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос такой.

Если я в ListView нажму на элемент индексом 2, то в БД должна удалиться строка с ID==4, Но как мне удалить если я не знаю какое там будет ID,

Если бы в БД ID обновлялись после удаления, я бы удалил по ID==3, НО ID==3 ВЕДЬ УЖЕ НЕТ, И ЕЕ ТАМ НЕ БУДЕТ БОЛЬШЕ, в этом и вся проблема моя. Вся позиция сбилась из - за этого

Comment: Покажите вашу модель данных, кою вы в БД храните и кою в списке отображаете.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, непонял. SQLITE БД. БД и список простой, там только текст

Comment: Вы берёте данные из БД, верно? Значит у вас есть доступ к id записей в момент составления списка. Значит вы можете сделать актуальный список записей с их id. И удаляя по позиции в списке вы можете передавать id, а не позицию в списке.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, Если я по буду полагаться на ID БД, то после удаления 1 жлемнта я просто не смогу знать какой ID теперь удалять

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31552/discussion-between-xtigrx-and-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не озвучиваете самого вопроса, точнее, как это связано с удалением не по ID. В принципе, SQL-синтаксис (у вас же SQLite, верно?) предполагает возможность удаления произвольных стрко по совпадению условий:

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE a = b AND (c = d OR e = f)
```

Однако это в любом случае неправильно. ID - это ***идентификатор***, уникальная ссылка на единицу данных, которая и позволяет его идентифицировать и работать с ним. Он ***и существует для того***, чтобы вы не позиции в списке считали, а имели уникальную ссылку на данные, не зависящую ни от чего. Вы должны ***всячески избегать*** любого другого способа создания ссылки на строки в таблице. Ваша задача (скорее всего) состоит не в насилии над базой данных, а в нахождении идентификатора элемента, закрепленного за строкой (я верю, что в терминах android это называется **binding**). После этого вы сможете удалить элемент, используя полученный идентификатор.

Comment: обновил вопрос .

Comment: @xTIGRx а ответ останется тем же. Вам не позицию элемента в списке надо искать, а сам элемент и его ID.